# how to auto run the realtime calculation code on javascript when load the page

Tags: javascript, laravel

now im doing laravel project. i implement Realtime calculation code use javascript. the script can run ok. but the problem is. when i want to load my form that already contain the number. the calculation not display. i need to input the value first to run the calculation.

here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
   
       $("tbody").on("input", function() {
           var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
           style: 'currency',
           currency: 'USD',
           });
   
           const totalcost = $(".getcost").map(function(i, input) {
               const val = input.value && !isNaN(input.value) ? +input.value : 0;
               $(input).closest("tr").find("td").eq(4).text(val)
               return val;
           }).get().reduce((acc, cur) => { acc += cur; return acc; }, 0)
           $("#totalcost").text(totalcost.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,'));
   
   
           const totalEach = $(".getcost").map(function(i, input) {
               const getcost = input.value && !isNaN(input.value) ? +input.value : 0;
               let  grossProfit = $(input).closest("td").next().find("input").val();
               grossProfit = grossProfit && !isNaN(grossProfit) ? +grossProfit : 0;
               const val = (getcost + (getcost * (grossProfit/100)))
               $(input).closest("tr").find("td").eq(4).text(val.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,'))
               return val;
           }).get().reduce((acc, cur) => { acc += cur; return acc; }, 0)
   
           $("#totalcosteach").text(totalEach.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,')) 
   
       });
    });
</script>
```

how do i can modify this code. i want, when i open the form page that already contain input number value. the calculation can run automatically.

please help

Comment: Maybe you need to trigger an `input` event when the page loads, so that your event listener fires: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545557/how-to-trigger-an-input-event-with-jquery

Comment: thank you for the respone. but i still confuse how to implement it.

Comment: After you set up your event listener, add this: `$("tbody").trigger("input");`